# Automatically name Computer using PowerShell get host name and MDT

Tags: powershell, deployment, mdt

My question is if it is possible to obtain the Domain Name of a computer in a Enterprise environment and use it as computer name in a MDT deployment.

I am aware that MDT has an option for setting the computer name here: Right cklick on Deployment Share - Rules

I would love to use the variable $CNAME (Computer Name) which I can successfully obtain using the follwing powershell commands as a variable for “OSDComputerName=“ in the deploymentshare settings.

---

This ps script gets me the right name:

1 Get IP

```
$IP=((ipconfig | findstr [0-9].\.)[0]).Split()[-1]
```

2 Do NSLOOKUP of IP

```
$Lookup=NSLOOKUP $IP
```

3 Adjust output with regular expressions and -replace modifiers to only contain the real computername without DNS suffix

```
$regex=$Lookup -match "(^.*\bName\b\:?\s*\b)[\w\d\s\-]*"
$replace1=$regex -replace "Name:    "
$CNAME=$replace1 -replace "*DNSSUFFIX*"
```

---

Is this possible? Otherwise, can I use the PowerShell Script in any way to rename the computer after the deployment has finished? E.g. which command can I use to use the variable $CNAME as new computer name?

Comment: I believe that you can use the Rename-Computer -ComputerName $Computer -NewName $NewComputerName once the computer is rebuilt, I'm not sure where your getting the name from before the system is built though?

Comment: That command needs PowerShell 3.0 to be installed (I need to run this for Windows 7 deployment) and in my tests it doesn’t even work with PS3.0 installed, most likely due to the computer I tested it on being in the domain at the time being. Will test next week if rename-computer -newname does work when the computer ist not in the domain. Anyway, this needs PowerShell 3.0 to be deployed first which I would like to avoid… Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

The following Script will use the IP Adress to query your DNS and get the name of the Computer in your Domain and pass it back to MDT as `OSDComputerName`

This works in an environment where the computers are named like `name.xx.yournamespace.de`

Add an nslookup.exe from a Windows ISO to your WinPE Boot Image (mount WinPE WIM with DISM and copy nslookup.exe into System32)

Adjust your customsettings.ini Rules, add:

```
UserExit=Setname.vbs
OSDComputerName=#SetName("%IPAddress%")#
```

Add a UserExit Script to your Deploymentshare Scripts-Folder, name it `Setname.vbs`

```
Function UserExit(sType, sWhen, sDetail, bSkip) 
 UserExit = Success 
End Function
Function SetName(sIP)
 Dim rName
 Set objShell = createobject("wscript.shell")
 strParams = "%comspec% /c nslookup  " & sIP & ""
 Set objExecObj = objShell.exec(strParams)
 Do While Not objExecObj.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
     strText = objExecObj.StdOut.Readline()
     If instr(strText, "dns-9") Then 
         strServer = trim(replace(strText,"(null):",""))
 Elseif instr (strText, "xx.yournamespace.de") Then
     strhost = trim(replace(strText,"(null)",""))
 End if
 Loop
rName = replace(strhost, ".xx.yournamespace.de", "")
SetName = rName
End Function
```

Adjust replacements to your Network. `SetName` will be passed back to MDT.

Hopefully this helps someone!